# How to change cell format in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I'm trying to edit a cell format to be able to write mathematical symbols in it.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Dim sheet As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application()
Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook = sheet.Workbooks.Add()
Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(workbook.Worksheets.Item(1), Excel.Worksheet)
worksheet.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
```

I get:

```
An error occurred while running the program: System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'NumberFormat' on type 'Range' not found.
```

In C#, this snippet works:

```
Excel.Application sheet = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = sheet.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.Item[1];
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].NumberFormat = "@";
```

What is wrong?